# MVVM - Invoke Control Method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am looking for a MVVM solution.
A Control is used in the View (lets call it V). The Control has a Method Foo(). That method can not be invoked by an event since its operation is not connected to any events of the control.
I need to invoke this method from the ViewModel, but of course the ViewModel has no knowledge about the view. Do you have any ideas how to extend the Control to enable a MVVM compliant invocation of V.Foo()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked my not accepted questions and found this one.
I remember I solved the issue by adding a **ICommand** dependecy property to the Control, which is bound using **OneWayToSource** with no updating. The *Execute()* call will call the method on the control.

Answer (score 0):

"of course the ViewModel has no knowlage about the view"?

If you are doping MVVM the ViewModel **has** to be awareof View.

You may be need has to look on [RoutedCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx) or [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx)

Comment: Tigran that's not entirely true, for instance in a View-First model. [Here is an example](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx) - (scroll down to "The Chicken or the Egg?") - The view might be the one that creates the VM and then the VM has no idea who the view is.

Comment: Please take a look at the question, this is NOT about simple command binding.

Comment: @Jaster: I read it naturally. The thing is that *this* architecture (whatever is it) it's not MVVM.  If you don't have *events* you have to have commands. Here what I see, is mismatch between definition of the question and actual problem OP faces.

Comment: There is not. Usually events are used to extend Controls with Commands/Properties. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

In the View Model create a Boolean which will signal the view to do the operation. If you have access to the control, create a dependency property which can be bound to the aforementioned Boolean and calls the method upon a change. If you don't have the ability to write a dependency property, create a behavior which will do the work.

Comment: Well this will work for once. Otherwise I would need to "reset" the property in the ViewModel after calling the behavior code... Otherwise the Property won't update a second time.

Comment: @Jaster One interaction behavior for true and another for false to toggle or even use an integer for a state machine approach.

Comment: Even though I use this implementation myself, I find if very ugly and hack-ish and will switch to the event publisher solution

Comment: @AlexDrenea I come from a Silverlight Xaml background where everything is asynchronous. To me this fits the _not knowing_ when data will arrive, hence flags and statuses used for behaviors makes this to me more elegant than _hackish_ because it is not a one off operation but the primary methodology of the asynchronous VM. But again it is just one option of many for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case I'd normally use a Messenger (e.g. MVVMLight) / Mediator / EventAggregator (e.g. Prism) patterns to notify the View that it should execute the method. With such a pattern you basically send a message from the VM to some recipient (in your case the View) without knowing who will handle it. Thus the view model does not need to know the view.

Furthermore, this pattern can be used to create general broadcast messages that can be handled my many recipients, without the sender knowing any of them.

Examples:

- [Realizing Navigation in WP7](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2011/01/06/navigation-in-a-wp7-application-with-mvvm-light.aspx)
- [MVVMLight Messenger for Loosely Coupled Events](http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.de/2011/05/mvvmlight-messenger-for-loosely-coupled.html)
- [MVVM Mediator Pattern](http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/mvvm-mediator-pattern/)
- [Event Aggregator in Prism](http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.de/2009/05/event-aggregator-in-prism-explorer.html)

and

- [Some of my ramblings on the MVVMLight messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A266919+messenger)

**PS:**

There are many valid cases for such an approach. However, it must be said that calling the View from the ViewModel should be avoided, if there is another solution.

To those who criticise the access to the view from the view model: Please keep in mind that MVVM is about empowering the user by giving her alternatives, not forcing rules upon them.

Comment: All these solutions have the same problem. They relay on a change within the view, which is not singaled since it shall be invoked by the ViewModel. The Mediator could only solve the problem if I had only one View (or only one ViewModel) which is not the case.

Comment: Speaking for MVVMLight: VM sends a message on the common message bus. The control or the view subscribes for the message and then calls Foo(). In this scenario the view model does not know anything about the view, yet the call to Foo() is initiated by it. With, the token parameter you can even implement an addressing scheme, that allows the routing from one view model to a view even if several instances of both classes exist. You just have to research the possibilities of the pattern, all I can do here is point you to the resources. If you need more you have to provide more information.

Comment: The token filtering would be mandatory, but this (from my point of view) is pretty ugly. You need to pass the viewmodel as token and check the datacontext of the view with the token. At the end this is an abuse/inversion of the messenger/mediator - which I do not like.

Comment: You need to pass an identifier not the view model, e.g. a name, a guid, etc.

Comment: When having to decide between architectural and semantic beauty, I'd definately go for the first. On the other hand if you really feel you should break a guideline for what ever reasons, nobody is going to send the police (Lauren's quote not mine). So if you need/want coupling between the view and the view model go ahead. The pattern I shown you is a way to get around that coupling, but it's not the only way. But if you go for the coupling of view and view model, just bear in mind you loose some benefits, e.g. testability.

Comment: providing a token from the VM to the V is coupling as well